# User Roles and Security Profiles

Tags: user-profile, security

How do I configure user roles as security profiles?  Is it feasible with Foundation and Windows Server on a hosted site.  Will I have access to Profile Services?

Thanks.

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a shared hosting service, ask the host to make you a site collection administrator.  Then you may add users to the web site and assign roles to them.